# Facebook returned empty data for me/feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with Facebook graph API. First time when I try to get home feed with URL https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/home/??access_token=accesstoken&until=1354639369&limit=40 all is good, I have a data. But when I diving deeper into the feed with changing "until" value (loading older messages) at some moment Facebook returned for me empty result:

{
   "data": [

]
}

I can not find the reason of this problem. May be it is Facebook restrict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook (as stated in the other answer) indeed returns for maximum a months worth of data. If your until timestamp is >30 days in the past it will return an empty result. A solution would be to use batch requesting and get 30 days at a time.

You can read more about batch requesting in the Facebook Graph API documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Answer (score 0):

facebook provide data for last 15 post or a month which one is maximum.